# How do you write this if/else statement for a boolean checker

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have these variables

```js
    let isactive
    let istradeable = true
    let issellable = false
    let isrevocable
    let isburnable
```

I have an if/else that basically look at these variables and checks if they are NOT null and if it's not assign it's value to a new variable. If it is NULL set variable to true

```
        if (isactive == null) {
        isactive = true
    } else {
        this.isactive = isactive
    }
    if (istradeable == null) {
        istradeable = true
    } else {
        this.istradeable = istradeable
    }
    if (issellable == null) {
        issellable = true
    } else {
        this.issellable = issellable
    }
    if (isrevocable == null) {
        isrevocable = true
    } else {
        this.isrevocable = isrevocable
    }
    if (isburnable == null) {
        isburnable = true
    } else {
        this.isburnable = isburnable
    }
```

This works but I'm looking for a simple function or maybe a better if/else statement that does the same thing. Thanks guys!

Comment: since you are changing the value of the variable itself, the number of if statements you will have to write is equal to `{no of variables}`. But if you assign the variables to a list or an object, you can write a for loop that does your work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for

```
this.isactive = (isactive == null) ? true : isactive;
this.istradeable = (istradeable == null) ? true : istradeable;
this.issellable = (issellable == null) ? true : issellable;
this.isrevocable = (isrevocable == null) ? true : isrevocable;
this.isburnable = (isburnable == null) ? true : isburnable;
```

or simpler

```
this.isactive = isactive == null || isactive;
this.istradeable = istradeable == null || istradeable;
this.issellable = issellable == null || issellable;
this.isrevocable = isrevocable == null || isrevocable;
this.isburnable = isburnable == null || isburnable;
```

Of course you could also write a function:

```
function from(value) {
    if (value == null) return true;
    else return value;
}
this.isactive = from(isactive);
this.istradeable = from(istradeable);
this.issellable = from(issellable);
this.isrevocable = from(isrevocable);
this.isburnable = from(isburnable);
```